# GPS Coordinates - finding closest entity based on current location

Tags: sql, sql-server, geolocation, gps

I have a table of 4,000 schools - each having their lat & long coordinates.
Each shop has a level (3 options).

I want to pass current lat, long coordinates, and find the 3 closest for each category of shop.

```
DECLARE @current_lat DECIMAL(12, 9)
DECLARE @current_long DECIMAL(12, 9)

SET @current_lat=55.151025 set @current_long=-7.455171

DECLARE @orig geography = geography::Point(@current_lat, @current_long, 4326);
SELECT * FROM
(
    (
        SELECT top 3 *, @orig.STDistance(geography::Point(s.Lat, s.Long, 4326)) AS distance
        FROM School s
        WHERE Level = 1
        order by distance asc
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT top 3 *, @orig.STDistance(geography::Point(s.Lat, s.Long, 4326)) AS distance
        FROM School s
        WHERE Level = 2
        order by distance asc
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT top 3 *, @orig.STDistance(geography::Point(s.Lat, s.Long, 4326)) AS distance
        FROM School s
        WHERE Level = 3
        order by distance asc
    )
) s
```

The code works fine, but it takes about 1 second to execute.
I have added non-clustered indexes to the lat, long & level columns.

Can someone suggest an improvement to make this a little snappier? Adding 1 second to an API call doesn't seem feasable.

Thanks

Execution Plan:

[image: Execution Plan]

[Execution Plan - Paste The Plan](https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1bjO7qx3)

Comment: Show us your execution plan using Paste The Plan

Comment: Yeah as I said, not as an image, using Paste The Plan.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1bjO7qx3

Comment: The geography stuff is pretty slow in SQL Server. You could add a materialized geography column to your table, which might easy the pressure off, and also play around with Spatial Indexes, although in *MY* expirience they're pretty sucky. If i were you, i'd just implement Haversine formula instead which calculates distance between two sets of Lat / lon points

Comment: Or use geometry datatype, it's faster, and you can calculate the real distance in the OUTER select

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Can you put an upper bound on the `distance` you're willing to consider? That is, can you change your specification to only consider distances of something like 100km or less? If so you can use [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) bounding-box calculations. [Check this out](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/).

Answer (score 0):

Rewrited as :

```
WITH T AS
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(GROUPING BY Level ORDER BY  @orig.STDistance(geography::Point(s.Lat, s.Long, 4326))) AS N
        @orig.STDistance(geography::Point(s.Lat, s.Long, 4326)) AS distance
 FROM School s
 WHERE Level BETWEEN 1 AND 3
SELECT * FROM T WHERE NCHAR >=3
ORDER BY Level, distance
```

Is it quicker ?

Do you have a geo index ?